# Вопрос по логике появления объектов

Tags: python, pygame

Зачем в данном python коде (c подключённой библиотекой pygame) нужна строчка в конце: strela.push = False?

```
if e.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
     if strela.push == True:
          strela.x = hero.x+15
          strela.y = hero.y-10    
          strela.push = False
```

P.S Этот кусок кода прописывает появление стрелы рядом с героем при нажатии на клавишу

Answer (score 1):

Без более расширенного куска кода сказать это трудно. Что есть `push`? Что есть `strela`? Как происходит отрисовка?
Настолько я понимаю, `strela` это ваш самописный спрайт, что я бы не рекомендовал использовать. Попробуйте использовать массив спрайтов, который уже есть в pygame: `pygame.sprite.Sprite` и [`pygame.sprite.Group`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group)

В итоге, ваш код должен быть похож на что-то вроде этого:

```
if e.key == pygame.K_SPACE and hero.arrow_count > 0
    arrow_sprite_group.add(Arrow(hero.x - 10, hero.y - 10, ...))
```

Где `arrow_sprite_group` - группа страйтов со стрелами, [pygame.sprite.Group](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group)

Где `Arrow` - класс стрелы, на базе pygame.sprite.Sprite

PS. А `push = False` там для того, чтобы нельзя было по нажатию space стрелу возвращать к герою, если я правильно понял логику кода

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю то это для того чтоб при нажатии
пробела действия выполнялось только один раз